# How to move marbles between tubes with the least amount of work

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Consider the following problem which I give a "physical" marbles/tubes description of -- the formal description is easy to obtain from this "physical" description.

> **Moving marbles between tubes.**  Let $N =2^n$ be a large positive integer, and $f(n)$ a sublinear function of $n$ such as $\sqrt{n}$ or $\log n$.  Suppose you are an automaton performing the following simple task: there are three tubes, labeled $A, B, C$ that marbles can be placed into.  Tubes $A$ and $B$ start empty while tube $C$ contains $N$ marbles all stacked in a tower.  A *step* involves picking a marble off from the top of tube $C$ (and $B$ if non-empty), and placing it at the bottom of tube $A$: thus if tube $A$ already has $k$ marbles in it, we must dump out all these marbles and place the new marble at the bottom -- this operation has a *cost* $k$.
> *Every step we are required to place one marble from Tube $C$ and one marble from Tube $B$ (if non-empty) at the bottom of tube $A$*.  But during a step *we may also* remove all $k$ marbles in $A$ from previous steps, and place them all into tube $B$, incurring a cost of $(k+l)f(k+l)$ if Tube $B$ already contains $l\geq 0$ marbles, or place them all back into tube $C$, incurring a cost of $Nf(N)$. Doing so allows us to "start fresh."

The problem, then, is as follows:

> **Problem.**  What is the optimal strategy for moving marbles between the tubes if we want to minimize the *average cost* over $N$ steps? Can we lower bound this average cost?

Comment: What would the answer be with $n=1,2,3,4$ i.e $N=2,4,8,16$?

Comment: Minimizing the average cost is the same as minimizing the total cost, right? Where do the costs of the form $x f(x)$ come from?

Comment: @Henry yes $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Karl yes by "average cost" I mean the average cost per step, i.e. if after $t$ steps the total cost is $C$, then average cost is $C/t$.

Comment: What I was suggesting was that you might try some calculations with small $n$